# Pattern for passing request context to business logic

Tags: object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

I'm working on a project in which I have a clear separation between domain logic and the logic that exposes these features using an API (or whatever). For this I'm using the Onion Architecture.

Now I want to implement authorization. E.g.: If the user is the manager of an employee, he can update their salary. But not for employees that report to different managers. For this, the domain logic will need to know which user it is, but I don't want to create a dependency on something like an HttpContext which typically contains the authenticated user.

Are there any patterns for this?

I was thinking about using some kind of (domain) context, but I wouldn't know how to pass this to the domain logic, without passing it to every call.

To specify the scope: I think the domain logic should only be concerned with authorization (can this user to this) and not authentication (is the user really who he says he is). Any information passed to the domain logic can therefore be trusted by the domain.

Cheers,
Quido.

PS: Any help specific for implementing this in .NET Core is also appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a DI container, my preferred approach here is to create a `ICurrentUserService` (or similar) which fetches the information for you.

The interface:

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    string GetUserName();
}
```

Then your Web project can implement it:

```
public class CurrentHttpUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string GetUserName()
    {
        var username = /* get username from context */
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Your DI container registers it:

```
services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentHttpUserService>();
```

And then your business logic can depend on the interface without needing to know how the proverbial sausage is made:

```
public class MyBusinessService
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService currentUserService;

    public MyBusinessService(ICurrentUserService currentUserService)
    {
        this.currentUserService = currentUserService;
    }

    public void MyBusinessMethod()
    {
        var username = currentUserService.GetUserName();

        /* Perform authorization check based on username */
    }
}
```

This keeps everything separate.

Also note that because of using an abstraction here, you are able to easily change how you identify a user. Not only is this great for testing (i.e. injecting a mocked identity), it can also be used in different ways.

For example, my project uses a JWT token to identify its user. That's great from a security perspective, but it's annoying to have to refresh that token when I'm developing locally. So I created another implementation of the user service:

```
public class LocalDebugUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string GetUserName()
    {
        return "myTestAccount";
    }
}
```

And then my DI container registers this hardcoded user service when I'm debugging. There's a few ways you can configure this, e.g. config files, but an `#IF DEBUG` tends to work well enough.

Comment: Thanks! This looks very nice! I'm currently using a POCO as implementation for the service, which is initialized in middleware, right after authentication/authorization in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any patterns for this?

The usual answer would be that your outer layers extract the information that you need from, for instance, the authorization token, and then pass that information to the domain model as an argument.

```
bob.updateSalary(20000, alice, orgChart)
```

In some cases, instead of having the application pass raw information to the domain model, you instead pass along affordances for obtaining that information.  This pattern is sometimes referred to as a DOMAIN SERVICE (see chapter 5 of the "blue book").

One pattern you might use is to wrap a domain service skin around your "request context", and then pass those capabilities (or a subset of them) to your domain model in a language the domain model understands.

Structurally, this normally looks like an abstraction defined in the domain model, and then implemented/specialized out in your application or infrastructure code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You describe the same as Flater, but that answer is a bit more specific, so I marked that as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> If the user is the manager of an employee, he can update their salary.

One of the core principles to always keep in mind is to **make things explicit**. Within the domain, users don't exist, only managers and employees. And *update a salary* doesn't sound like the **ubiquitous language** of a manager, they would perhaps say *give this employee a pay raise*

In the domain you could have a `Manager` class with a method `GivePayRaiseTo(Employee employee, Salary newSalary)`

When the domain is modelled this way, it doesn't need to know about the user who is calling the method. You can move the authorization entirely to the application service, keeping all that unnecessary complexity out of the domain layer.

In the application layer you fetch employees and managers from their respective repositories, the code could look something like:

```
var currentUserId = ... // get the current user id from the context
var manager = ManagerRepository.GetById(currentUserId);
if(manager == null)
{
   throw new UnauthorizedException();
}
var employee = EmployeeRepository.GetById(request.employeeId);    
var newSalary = new Salary(request.salary);

manager.GivePayRaiseTo(employee, newSalary);
```

Comment: Although you're completely right, you're completely ignoring the question that is asked. The question was not about how to DDD a salary raise, but the question is about authorization.

Comment: @Quido You're right, I didn't address it. In my head it was obvious how modelling the domain like this would solve the issue. I edited my answer, hopefully it makes more sense now.